# MyBB find_replace_templatesets not working

Tags: php, mybb

I've been trying to update a template in my plugin for an hour now, but unsuccessfuly.

Template I'm editing is showthread_newreply - but the code doesn't work in header template too.

```
<a href="newreply.php?tid={$tid}" class="button new_reply_button"><span>{$lang->new_reply}</span></a>&nbsp;
```

I want to add a button after "New reply" anchor with this code:

```
function myplugin_activate() {
    require_once MYBB_ROOT."/inc/adminfunctions_templates.php";

    find_replace_templatesets(
        "showthread_newreply",
        "#" . preg_quote('</a>&nbsp;') . "#i",
        '</a>&nbsp;<button>My Button</button>'
    );
}
```

My plugin file name is myplugin.php and I know it's supposed to change the template when I'm activating the plugin as it is in that function.

It doesn't work.
I tried many other combinations, changing the template, changing what's getting searched and replaced...

Regards.

Comment: Maybe it's related to the activate or install function? I just tried the exact code without the function wrapper in index.php and it worked.

Comment: Just copied the code in Hello World plugin, it worked.

Comment: Yay, I've been editing the wrong freakin file for an hour now, guess what - when I put the code in the right file it worked.